# filtering by a type ( type is not in db, model is in db) field using 'not' is not working prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I have this type

```
type Details {
  birthday String?
  phone    String?
  email    String?
}
```

and this model

```
model profiles {
  id           String            @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  schools      School[]
  details      Details?
  skills       Skill[]
  allSkills    String?
}
```

I try to query filtering with a 'not'

```
const profiles = await prisma.profiles.findMany({
        where: {
          user: {
            email: {
              not: null,
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

but it's not working, typescript doesn't suggest 'not' for email (which is string | undefined | null ) **whereas**
when I change prisma type to a prisma model like this: then typescript suggest 'not'

```
model Details {
  birthday String?
  phone    String?
  email    String?
}
```

SO WE CAN'T FILTER THE SAME WAY ON A TYPE THAN ON A MODEL ?

Filtering with 'not' should work for any type or model i guess
thanks

Comment: In your find query in where clause you are filtering on user's email, but I can't see any relation field named `User`.

Comment: are you a prisma user? I changed the type to a model, because i was not able to filter the same way without a model. can we filter the same way on a type than on a model?

Comment: @NurulSundarani can't be the mistake, in any case the most of the db schema was changed so your answer is not anymore relevant